# Get the physical size of data deleted?

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete, data-size

When doing a `DELETE` statement, I know you can get the number of rows deleted, with `@@ROWCOUNT`.

Is there a way to get the size of the data deleted, in bytes?
Not something I need, but I'm just really curious, it would be a nice feature for reporting.

Specifically I'm working in SQL Server (2019).

The use case I'm thinking, is we have a nightly script which purges old data from client DBs, as we charge them for storage space. And the task sends a slack notification after it finishes, saying how many rows it deleted. It would be cool to be able to add how many bytes of data it removed.

Comment: You can calculate average size of the row by help of this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25531/how-can-i-get-the-actual-data-size-per-row-in-a-sql-server-table and then you can multiply with the number of rows. It won't be exact but it can get you a figure to report.

Comment: Can't you use  sp_spaceused 'Tablename' before and after the delete run?

Comment: Easiest is probably run `sp_spaceused` for the table before and after, since there is a lot of variability that can't be easily calculated just based on row count (any variable length column, for example). But also, do you count fragmentation?

Comment: Hmm, some good ideas! I'll have to play around with adding those to my script.

Answer (score 0):

You can output the data size into a temp table, then sum it up.

```sql
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (size bigint NOT NULL);

DELETE SomeTable
OUTPUT DATALENGTH(deleted.Column1) + DATALENGTH(deleted.Column2) + DATALENGTH(deleted.Column3)
INTO @tmp (size)
WHERE whatever;

SELECT SUM(size) AS sizeBytes, COUNT(*) AS countRows
FROM @tmp;
```